# Can't serialize minidom tree with io module

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, minidom

I have to work with legacy code which use [`xml.dom.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) (and I can't migrate to [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)).

I'd like to parse this minimal sample:

```
<body>
    <p>English</p>
    <p>Français</p>
</body>
```

The following function works perfectly:

```
import codecs
import xml.dom.minidom


def transform1(src_path, dst_path):
    tree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(src_path)
    # ...
    with codecs.open(dst_path, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        tree.writexml(fd, encoding="utf-8")
```

But, if I change to use `io` instead, everything goes wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/minidom_demo.py", line 23, in <module>
    transform2("sample.xml", "result.xml")
  File "/path/to/minidom_demo.py", line 18, in transform2
    tree.writexml(fd, encoding="utf-8")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1747, in writexml
    writer.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="%s"?>%s' % (encoding, newl))
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

If I open the file in binary mode (`mode="wb"`) I have another exception saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/minidom_demo.py", line 23, in <module>
    transform2("sample.xml", "result.xml")
  File "/path/to/minidom_demo.py", line 18, in transform2
    tree.writexml(fd, encoding="utf-8")
  ...
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 298, in _write_data
    writer.write(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The minidom writer seems to be unaware of Unicode.

Why does it work with `codecs`?

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `writexml` method seems to dump `str` always. Reading the documentation tells me that its `encoding` argument only adds the encoding attribute to the XML header.

> Changed in version 2.3: For the Document node, an additional keyword
>   argument encoding can be used to specify the encoding field of the XML
>   header.

You can try instead:

```py
fd.write(tree.toxml(encoding="utf-8").decode("utf-8"))
```

The above will save the XML as UTF-8 and specifies the encoding in the XML header as well.

If you do not specify encoding, it will still save as UTF-8, but the encoding attribute won't be included in the header.

```py
fd.write(tree.toxml())
```

If you specify encoding, but don't `decode()`, it will raise an exception as `toxml()` returns a `str`, which is quite strange, though.

```py
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```